# Форматирование числа в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как можно получить строковое представление числа с определенным количеством символов, т.е. если число короче, то вначале добавить нули. Например: 5 -> '00005', 123 -> '00123'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
var num = 135;
var numF = addnull(num);
console.log(numF);

var num = 2;
var numF = addnull(num);
console.log(numF);

function addnull(str) {
  str = str + '';
  if (str.length < 5) {
    str = '0' + str;
    return addnull(str);
  } else {
    return str;
  };
}
```

Comment: я тоже думал о чем-то подобном, но надеялся что есть более простой способ, как в Java например )))

Comment: с отрицательными не сработает. А то можно было бы и [так](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10073788/556876)

Answer (score 2):

С использованием функции repeat:

```
if (!String.prototype.repeat) // полифил для repeat()
    String.prototype.repeat= function(count) {
        return new Array(count+1).join(this);
    };
var s= v.toString();
if(s.length<n) s= s[0]=='-'? '-'+'0'.repeat(n-s.length)+s.substr(1) : '0'.repeat(n-s.length)+s;
```

Comment: `-9` => `000-9`

Comment: хм, да, сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 1):

```js
var num = 135;
var numF = addnull(num);
console.log(numF);

var num = 2;
var numF = addnull(num);
console.log(numF);

function addnull(str) {

  return ("0000" + str).substr(-5);

}
```

Comment: тоже только для неотрицательных